# Event driven turn based text game, creating an object

Tags: java

I have a method `processInput` that is activated when it is the user's turn, the variable `prompt` lets me know at which point of the game the user is.

So I have a prompt "Find a worthy opponent press F". If the user pressed "F" I generate an `Enemy` object and then randomly let user/opponent attack each other. After that it prompts "Press A to attack" when it's the user's turn again, but because that previous prompt (`if`) created an object, the compiler doesn't know if it was executed to allow me to reference that object.

In the last if-clause in `processInput` at the line `player.attack(e);`, `e` might not have been initialized yet, so I don't really know how to resolve this issue.

```
public class inputListener implements ActionListener{
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            String inputLog = input.getText();
            input.setText("");
            console.append(input + "\n");
            processInput(inputLog);       
        }

        void processInput(String inputLog){
            input.setEnabled(false);
            Enemy e;
            if(prompt.startsWith("What is your name")){
                if(inputLog.isEmpty()){
                    player.setName("Bob");
                    console.append("...\nYour name therefore is Bob");

                }else{
                    player.setName(inputLog);
                    console.append("Alright "+player.getName()+"...\n");
                }
                choosePath();
            }else if(prompt.startsWith("If you wish to find a worthy opponent")){
                if(inputLog.equalsIgnoreCase("f")){
                    e = generateEnemy();
                    console.setText("");
                    console.append(e.getClass().getSimpleName()+" Level: "+e.getLvl());
                    console.append("\nHP: "+e.getHP());
                    console.append("\n\n\n");

                    if(Math.random()>0.49){
                        userTurn("Press A to attack");
                    }else{
                        e.attack(player);
                        if(!player.isDead()){
                           userTurn("Press A to attack");
                        }
                    }                
                }
            }else if(prompt.startsWith("Press A to attack")){
                player.attack(e);
                if(!player.isDead()||!e.isDead()){
                    e.attack(player);
                    userTurn("Press A to attack");
                }else if(e.isDead()){
                    console.append("\nYou have killed "+e.getClass().getSimpleName()+"!\n\n");
                    choosePath();
                }

            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

How are you prompting the user for input?  Can you exclude the "attack" option if e is null?  Otherwise if they do choose "attack" than skip it if e is null.

```
} else if(prompt.startsWith("Press A to attack")) {
    if (e != null) { // enemy might not be initialized yet
        player.attack(e);
        if (!player.isDead()||!e.isDead()) {
            e.attack(player);
            userTurn("Press A to attack");
        }
        else if(e.isDead()) {
            console.append("\nYou have killed "+e.getClass().getSimpleName()+"!\n\n");
            choosePath();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: e!=null requires me to at the beggining of processinput state enemy e = null; which would always turn it null and destroy my object. The way I prompt user for input void userTurn(String prompt){
        console.append(this.prompt = prompt);
        input.setEnabled(true);
        input.requestFocus();
    }

Comment: Checking for null shouldn't require you to set it to null.  You are already declaring it above, so it gets initialized to null.

Comment: It does shows me 'variable e might not have been initialized'